# Pattern / solution for Boolean decision making chains

Tags: java, design-patterns, patterns-and-practices

I need a solution for decision making chain. There are number of criteria that may return true, false or be inconclusive. A non-functional code (Java) would look like this:

```
Boolean res = nullValuesCheck(fieldValue, node);
if (res != null) {
    return res;
}
res = typeCheck(node);
if (res != null) {
    return res;
}
res = dictCheck(dict, fieldValue);
if (res != null) {
    return res;
}
return finalCheck(fieldName, fieldValue); //also returns a Boolean
```

I'm considering creating an extended predicate that would return a nullable `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, so that an inconclusive result could be returned.

I tried googling, but found no apparent solution (got lot of mishits on some simple java problems instead). I am wondering whether there exists a pattern, a library maybe, that would handle this problem properly. The problem seems generic and simple to solve and someone must've solved it already. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like Trinary Logic, you might be able to find more by searching for that!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `Optional.or()`. As in:

```java
check1()
.or(() -> check2())
.or(() -> check3())
.orElse(false)
```

Checks return `Optional<Boolean>`, so `Optional.empty()` if they don't decide, otherwise they contain the boolean decision. Result of the whole thing is a boolean with the first decision that was not empty, or the default value at the end if all were empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your chain is a *collection* of checks, so why not treat it as such?

```
public interface ICheck
{
    bool? Execute();
}

public class NullValuesCheck : ICheck
{
    public NullValuesCheck(Value fieldValue, Node node)
    {
        //set fields
    }

    public bool? Execute()
    {
        // use fields
    }
}

public class CheckCollection
{
    public CheckCollection(params ICheck[] checks)
    {
        //save the collection
    }

    public bool? Execute()
    {
        bool? result = null;
        foreach (var check in checks)
        {
            result = check.Execute();
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

// in your code
return new CheckCollection(
    new NullValuesCheck(fieldValue, node),
    new TypeCheck(node),
    //...
).Execute();
```

That way, you avoid repeating the "check result and execute next if null" logic everywhere you have a chain of checks, and can define your chain in a more OO way. The example above is in C#, but I think the Java implementation would be fairly similar.

Comment: I have no problem making my own implementation, I wanted to know whether an implementation already exists and/or the pattern has na name. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear why you need a fancier solution than what you've already sketched out. Is the list of checks long or dynamic or something?

You could return `Optional<Boolean>` instead of `Boolean` to make it clear the methods might not return a result. Then you could use `Optional.or`like suggested in another answer.

If you have to deal with a long or dynamic list of checks then you could write a function that returns the first present result from a List of Suppliers:

```
<T> Optional<T> firstPresentResult(List<Supplier<Optional<T>>> suppliers) {
    return suppliers.stream()
            .map(x -> x.get())
            .filter(x -> x.isPresent())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

Alternatively you could iterate:

```
<T> Optional<T> firstPresentResult(List<Supplier<Optional<T>>> suppliers) {
    for (Supplier<Optional<T>> s: suppliers) {
        if (s.get().isPresent()) {
            return s.get();
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Then you could feed the method with a list of checks

```
return firstPresentResult(
        Arrays.asList(
                () -> nullValuesCheck(fieldValue, node), 
                () -> typeCheck(node),
                () -> dictCheck(dict, fieldValue),
                () -> finalCheck(fieldName, fieldValue)
            )
        );
```

Answer (score -3):

It can be reduced to one expression with

```
Boolean res;
return ((res= nullValuesCheck(fieldValue, node)) != null)
    ? res
    : ((res= typeCheck(node)) != null)
        ? res
        : ((res= dictCheck(dict, fieldValue)) != null)
            ? res
            : finalCheck(fieldName, fieldValue);
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this to my worst enemy.